# Angular JS - How to populate ng-Grid , on change of combo

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular js.

I have a requirement that, in one page we have following components

1] Combo

2] Ng-Grid

For this I have two different controllers, comboCtrol, gridCtrl.
in ComboCtrl

```
self.onSelectTable= function(item) { 
   $rootScope.$broadcast('reloadGrid',self.tableRec);
```

}

in gridCtrl

```
     self.myGrid = {   }
     $scope.$on('reloadGrid', function(event,data) { 
         self.myTable=myService.getTableRecords(); 
     }
```

Now on combo change, I need to populate ng-Grid , by calling DB.
Since there are two different controller, I have used broadCast. But I want to understand , is there any best approach for this other than broadCast,emit?

Please guide me for this.

Comment: What you have will work but consider what happens if you have two grids showing different information.  Changing the combo on one grid would end up changing the other grid since your events are going out globally.  On the other hand, if you nest the combo controller inside of the grid controller then the grid scope is now the parent of the combo scope.  If you emit an event from the combo controller then it travels upward to the parent grid.  Furthermore, the combo can access the parent update function directly possibly eliminating the need for events completely.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , by using the hierarchy of the controller , we can call the gridCtrl's function.

$scope.main.testFunCall(self.tableRecord);
 
But I am using self instead of $scope , so in this case its not working 

like 

self.main.testFunCall(self.tableRecord);

Can you please suggest , what is wrong here.

Comment: I just started using the "controller as" approach.  Not sure what to advise.  Pretty sure you can still inject a scope.  Emitting a message might be the best way to go here.  It only needs to travel up one level and reduces coupling.  Maybe start a new question on the best way for a child controller to communicate to it's parent?